# Reload an animation (toggle menu) JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie to javascript so i'm here to ask for your help.
It's for a responsive navbar with JS.

When the user clicks on the toggle button, the menu appears (with an animation) or disappears. It's done. But I want to do something more, when the user clicks on one of the links of this menu, the menu is hidden. My issue is that when the user clicks on the toggle button again after that, the animation doesn't work, so the menu doesn't appears. It only works once, when the page is loaded. 
I want the animation to run every time we click on this toggle button, whether by having closed the menu via the toggle button or one of the links.

I tried to remove the animation when the menu is closed

```
link.addEventListener('click', function(){
        link.style.animation = '';
    })
```

in a forEach, when I click on the toggle button, only one link appears, since the animation is only removed on the link clicked, but not on the others. I don't know what do to make it works.. Help please.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ytj8a13m/4/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, that is very useful to include fiddles in the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be adding the event listeners inside other event listeners. Your code can be greatly simplified by moving all the code to toggle the menu into one function and adding it as a click event listener to the burger button and each of the navigation links.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsvxgz4q/

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    // Toggle button
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    // Two lists
    const navs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links');
    // Get individual links
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    function toggleMenu(){
     navs.forEach(nav=>{
       nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
      });
      navLinks.forEach((link,index)=>{
        if (link.style.animation) {
                  link.style.animation = '';
        } else {
          link.style.animation = `navLinkFade  0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.7}s`;
        }
      });
      burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    }
 burger.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
 navLinks.forEach(link=>{
     link.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
    });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


nav{
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height:100px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #00000029;
}

.logo img{
    width:120px;
}

.nav-links{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    width:40%;
}



.nav-links li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1em;
    letter-spacing: 3.2px;
}

/* mobile */

.burger{
    display:none;
}

.burger div{
    width:25px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    /*
    .logo{
        display:none;
    }
    */

    body{
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }

    .nav-links{
        z-index:3000;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        background-color:#fff;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items:center;
        width:50%; /* width bar menu */
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .links-left{
        height:36vh;
        top:100px;
    }

    .links-right{
        height:calc(100vh - (36vh + 100px));
        top:calc(36vh + 100px);
    }

    .nav-links li{
        opacity:0; /* hide links */
    }

    .burger{
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        left:5%;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
}

/* When click on the burger we add this class */
.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

/* Animation */

/* Animate links */
@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity:0;
        transform: translateX(-50px);
    } to{
        opacity:1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

@keyframes navFade{
    from{
        box-shadow: 4px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } to {
        box-shadow: 4px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
}

/* Animate toggle button */
.toggle .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2{
    opacity:0;
}

.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <div class="burger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav-links links-left">
                <li><a href="#one">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="logo">
                <div>LOGO</div>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav-links links-right">
                <li><a href="#three">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#four">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#five">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: @elisa No problem!

Comment: I wanted to ask you something else if it doesn't bother you! It seems like the menu is acting weird on desktop version, and since these animations should be applied only on mobile version, I tried to use match media and call the function in it like this but it doesn't work :

const mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 768px)" );
if (mq.matches){
    navSlide();
}

Did I miss something ?

Comment: @elisa You may want to ask a new question. The animations are working fine for me on desktop.